# Rails named_scope with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have 3 tables - films, films_genres (for connect 2 tables) and genres.
In Model film.rb - has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
In Model genre.rb - has_and_belongs_to_many :films

So, how I can write this sql code:

SELECT * FROM `genres` INNER JOIN `films_genres` ON `genres`.id = `films_genres`.genre_id WHERE (`films_genres`.film_id = 1 )

with named_scope in Model film.rb for show all film rolled genres?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :by_genre, lambda { |*genres|
    {
      :include => :genres,
      :conditions => [ "genres.id IN (?)", genres.map(&:id) ]
    }
  }
end

Film.by_genre(western, sci_fi).find(:all)
```

I made this one slightly more complex in order to specify multiple genres as part of your named scope. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In English, what are you trying to pull from the DB? To retrieve the genres for a particular film just do:

```
@genres = @film.genres
```

Answer (score 0):

chap! I try to pool from the db list of genres connected to the film. And my question is: how I can to do this using named_scome in film.rb Model? I need this for films filter.
Link for example: http://clearcove.ca/blog/2008/12/recipe-restful-search-for-rails/#more-218

Databases:

films:
id
name
descr
year

films_genres:
id
film_id
genre_id

genres:
id
name

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to have some kind of dynamic named_scope, but I'm still not quite sure why.

Have you looked at the railscasts on the subject? http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope and http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes